What requirements should we have for prior research
In Getting started with FAQ customisations @JeromyAnglim mentioned the idea of discussing prior research requirements and apart from discussing What to do with homework questions? I believe no real discussion has been made regarding the matter.
I feel having a prior research requirement will help deal with the homework type questions as these questions will be more geared to tackling those areas the OP does not understand, rather than the kind of "this is my question, please answer it for me" questions I am seeing a lot lately.
When someone says, for example,

I suspect that a or b will cause c

What makes them suspect that? What have they read to come up with that hypothesis?
Anyone can come up with a hypothesis, but is it based on information they have read or is it purely supposition? If it is supposition, have they tried to confirm it? What did they Google?
I feel some questions need to be more based on the information they have found and not just plucked out of the air.
So, what prior research requirements shall we set for questions? Will we accept just a Wikipedia link or do we require something substantial such as research papers or scientific magazines etc?

It seems that you make a duplicate answer and close it yourself. May I ask why you did that?

@Ooker - The duplicate was highlighted to me so I went to close, but had to wait for a mod to hammer it closed as the SE system registered my closure as a vote. In the meantime, I put my response into the duplicate question.
